# Java - Select All GUI Components of Type

Tags: java, swing, components

I'm trying to code my program so that all the components on my JFrame have a consistent colour scheme. To be able to do this, I wanted to use Java's for-each loop to affect each component of the same type. I have tried it like this to colour the JPanels, but it has had no affect.

```
public void colourGUI()
{
    for (Component comp : this.getComponents())
    {
        if (comp instanceof JPanel)
        {
            ((JPanel) comp).setOpaque(true);
            comp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        }
    }
}
```

I would have imagined this would work, but when I loaded the application it hadn't taken affect.
I'm reasonably new to Java, and I have previously used C# for programs like this where I would have used C#'s `OfType<>` method. I was hoping Java would have some kind of equivalent but I haven't found anything yet.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to accomplish what I'm looking to do? I imagine I'm missing something really obvious!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Could it be you are not using `repaint()` and `revalidate()`?

Comment: Hi, like I say I'm not overly familiar with Java's methods. When are where would I need to use these? @Dan

Comment: I just posted an answer. If it doesn't work drop a comment

Comment: Responded to your post. Think it's almost there but something is still just not firing for some reason. @Dan

Comment: As camickr pointed out my first answer was completely wrong. Can you post some more code? I posted some example code below of your code + implementation

Comment: @marcuthh Accordingly to my past experience, for loop and for-each loop does have a difference. Try changing your for-each loop to a normal for loop and test again. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: I've only just seen your last post, I'll test now and let you know. Thanks @Dan

Comment: Done with a regular for-loop. Works as expected! Thanks a lot @Dan

Comment: You're not going to find an `OfType<>` in Java, since it has no extension methods and even if it did, its generics are not strongly typed at runtime. -- Generally, you see methods take an instance of a class with the parameter named `clazz` (this is equivalent to the `System.Type` in C# -- except they pass it around like a parameter named `clazz` instead of just inferring it from the object).

Answer (score 2):

I apologise for my first answer. As shown in this example your code,

```
public void colourGUI()
{
    for (Component comp : this.getComponents())
    {
        if (comp instanceof JPanel)
        {
            ((JPanel) comp).setOpaque(true);
            comp.setBackground(Color.gray);
        }
    }
}
```

, does work without change.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private Box boxHolder;
    private JPanel scrollPaneContainer;

    Test(int i) {
        super("Test Frame");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(initScrollPane(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(initButtonAdd(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            boxHolder.add(createPanel());
        }

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component initButtonAdd() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Recolour");
        button.setBackground(Color.green);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (Component comp : boxHolder.getComponents())
                {
                    if (comp instanceof JPanel)
                    {
                        ((JPanel) comp).setOpaque(true);
                        comp.setBackground(Color.gray);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private Component initScrollPane() {
        scrollPaneContainer = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        boxHolder = Box.createVerticalBox(); 
        scrollPaneContainer.add(boxHolder, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane jSP = new JScrollPane(scrollPaneContainer);
        jSP.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        return jSP;
    }

    private Component createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(randomColor());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        panel.add(new JLabel("a colored Panel"));
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override 
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int indexPosition  = boxHolder.getComponentZOrder(panel);
                try
                {
                    boxHolder.remove(indexPosition);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
                try //Will only add here if you have a component in index position 1
                {
                    boxHolder.add(createPanel(),indexPosition);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
                scrollPaneContainer.revalidate();
            }
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        });
        return panel;
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat() / 2f ;
        float g = rand.nextFloat() / 2f;
        float b = rand.nextFloat() / 2f;
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        return randomColor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(6);
    }
}
```

Can you post some more code from your GUI?

Comment: Just tried this and no change at all, is there anything more fundamental than this that it could be?

Comment: First of all the order should be revalidate() and repaint(). However, there is no need to do this as Swing components do this automatically whenever the property of a component is changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The basic code looks reasonable, but without the `SSCCE` we can't tell the context of how this code is being used. For example we don't know what this.getComponents() refers to.

I would guess the problem is that your code doesn't use recursion so you are not actually getting a list of all the components on the frame. This is easy enough to test, just add a display statement in your loop to see how many panels you actually find.

The structure of a frame is more complex than you think. Take a look at [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#rootpane) for a better description of the structure.

You can use the [Swing Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class which does use recursion to get all the child components of a given type.